# Android background processing, handle result and Activity lifecycle

Tags: android, asynchronous, service, background

I have a general problem with Android background processing, how to properly deal with it?

Imagine this scenario:

1. Users starts Activity with Fragment.
2. Fragments starts fetching data from network by using IntenService.
3. IntentService provide result back to Fragment via LocalBroadcast
   system.

[image]

BroadcastReciever in Fragment is registered/unregistered in onResume()/onPause(). Everything looks good, however when user press HOME button right after 2) the result broadcast from IntentService has been lost. It happen becouse Fragment unregistered their BroadcastReceiver in onPasue() callback.

There is any general pattern to avoid this issue? 
Using ResultReceiver instead of BroadcastReceiver would be better for this prupouse?

I have tired ResultReceiver, in this case I send ResultReceiver to service in Bundle (it implements Parcelable interface) but after recreation Activity due to changing screen orientation ResultReceiver has "dirty" reference to previusly created Activity which can cause bugs.

Comment: Do you mean to update the UI as soon as the the background service finishes fetching data? If so, you could just replace it with an asynchronous network call. That way the request is destroyed when the calling activity/fragment is destroyed.

Comment: Yes, I mean update UI after background work is finish, but I am searching for most general solution, not only for Internet connection, that can handle background procesing with delivering result and maitain Activity lifecycle.

I have benn also using AsyncTask and simple ThreadExecutor but they dont fits my needs.

Answer (score 0):

Your IntentService can create a notification on task completion, with a pending intent back to your activity, in case your activity goes to background before receiving the task completion broadcast.

If you are thinking about launching the activity on task completion, after user exits the app (via home or back button), it is not a suggested UI pattern. From android developer website:

> A status bar notification should be used for any case in which a
>   background service needs to alert the user about an event that
>   requires a response. A background service should never launch an
>   activity on its own in order to receive user interaction. The service
>   should instead create a status bar notification that will launch the
>   activity when selected by the user.

Comment: This is interesing solution but handling result back to fragment should be transparent to user, in your answer the user should click on notification, correct my comment if i am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I just create my own solution but I am not sure that is correct. My solution handle providing result back by static cache in those scenarios:

I)

- Fragment start IntentService to fetch data
- User press HOME button and result arrived when BroadcastReceiver was
  unregistered

II)

- Fragment start IntentService to fetch data
- User rotate device and Fragment was recreated, during this process
  result arrived when BroadcastReceiver was unregistered

[my_answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKz48.png)

This solution consumes memory because we hold last result in static cache. To holds more than one result I recommend to use [LruCache](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html/%22LruCache%22) from Android, however in this case you should set id for every request (ex. timestamp?).

Could you check if my solution is correct? It is tested and works good but I don't know if my way is the best way for this problem.